# How can I read values of parameters via URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create an action controller that reads the url parameter and then does stuff accordingly but I don't know what to do next.

The following is the Index controller. I want to read the 'code' url parameter and then do stuff with it.

```
public ActionResult Index(string code)
        {
//do stuff with 'code' param details
                return View();
        }
```

I have also added the following in the route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Code",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{code}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
            );

    }
```

Whenever I try to manipulate the url, nothing happens, and when I use breakpoints, code param stays null.

the following are the type of urls I have tried, but nothing works:

```
http://localhost:49218/?code=1234
http://localhost:49218?code=1234
http://localhost:49218/Index/?code=1234
```

Comment: Your route says that code should be found in path but your URLs have "code" as a query parameter. Just delete "Code" route, or alternatively try URL like this: http://localhost:49218/Home/Index/1234

Answer (score 1):

Why you don make your action like this

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
//do stuff with 'id' param details
                return View();
        }
```

And delete your code route.

You can use these urls for example

```
http://localhost:49218/Home/Index/1234
//or
http://localhost:49218/Home/Index/mycode1
```

or you can use attribute routing:

```
[Route("/")]
[Route("~/Home/Index/{id?}")]
[Route("~/{id}")]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
//do stuff with 'id' param details
                return View();
        }
```

In this case you can use this kind of url:

```
http://localhost:49218
//or
http://localhost:49218/1234
//or
http://localhost:49218/mycode1
//or
http://localhost:49218/Home/Index/1234
//or
http://localhost:49218/Home/Index/mycode1
```

but config attribute routing before:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: bruh thank you! this just saved me quite the headache!